# Does dynamodb support something like an "in" clause in its queries?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Say I have table of photos and users.

Given I have a list of users I'm following `[user1,user2,...]` and I want to get a list of photos of people I'm following.

How can I query the table of photos `where photo.createdBy in [user1,user2,user3...]`

I saw that dynamodb has a batch operation, but that takes a primary key, and in this case we would be querying against a secondary index (createdBy).

Is there a way to do a query like this in dynamodb?

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying purely on `photo.createdBy`, then you should create a [global secondary index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html):

> To speed up queries on non-key attributes, you can create a **global secondary index**. A global secondary index **contains a selection of attributes from the table**, but they are organized by a primary key that is different from that of the table. The index key does not need to have any of the key attributes from the table; it doesn't even need to have the same key schema as a table.

This will, of course, only retrieve one item. To limit results when returning more items, use a [`FilterExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#FilteringResults):

> With a Query or a Scan operation, you can provide an **optional filter expression** to refine the results returned to you. A filter expression lets you apply conditions to the data after it is queried or scanned, but before it is returned to you. **Only the items that meet your conditions are returned.**

This can be applied to a `Filter` or `Scan`, but be careful of using too many Read Capacity Units when scanning for matching entries.

Comment: does that support querying with an in clause?  I only see documentation that says you can use equal or other operators but no array in clauses

Comment: You can use IN operator in a filter expression, which means in this case you need to scan your table and filter by photo.createdBy IN [user1, user2, user3] etc.

Comment: So basically a full scan of the table to look for 3 values. Then if I am understanding this correctly, the answer to OP's question is - "No, you cannot _efficiently_ use an IN query in dynamodb" ?